# How to trim audio while Recording?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I want to recored a hour long Audio. And so I won't loose the whole recording if some thing happens, I want to save the recording every 5 minutes,

Is it possible? and if yes, how?

Comment: You could save the audio as multiple files of length 5s.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I did eventually, thanks any ways.